# How to override styles in Iframe?

Tags: css, iframe, twitter

I am using the twitter follow us widget from https://twitter.com/about/resources/followbutton and I would like to change the color of the text. Right now the text is aqua blue which doesn't work well on my sites background.

Is there a way to override the styling inside the iframe? If so, how?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's no way to modify the DOM or style of the content in an iframe. The best you can do is link to a different-styled iframe, as twitter offers both light and dark themes.

EDIT: That being said, there are several parameters in the `<a>` tag that can be used to customize the theme even further. Try modifying the `data-button`, `data-text-color`, and `data-link-color` parameters to your liking!

Comment: oh, I didn't even notice those parameters. Nice catch :)